# i have created div java script with absolute positioning...but

Tags: html

the margin of all computers is different.so the images are not placed where they r supposed to be

```
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 25px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 805px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='yellow';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 20px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 785px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='violet';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 20px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 765px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='indigo';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 20px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 745px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>

<div id="mydiv" style="height: 20px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 576px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='green';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 20px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 556px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='orange';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 20px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 536px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='brown';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 20px;width: 503px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 519px; width: 130px;width:328px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='violet';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>

<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='indigo';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 659px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='brown';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 684px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='green';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 709px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='pink';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 734px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='violet';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>

<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 885px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='indigo';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 905px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='green';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 930px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:25px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='blue';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 150px;width: 40px; left: 955px; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 596px; width: 10px;width:32px;background:black" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">

    </div>
```

Comment: please post some code or something, we are not psychics.

Comment: what the problem you have. tell them in detail. maybe another one can solve the grammar here.

Answer (score 0):

- Images? There are only div elements in your example.
- You can't give all elements the same id, id must be unique (HTML 4.01 and XHTML)

Other than that, the example you have posted gives a "square donut" shape in Firefox 3.6, Chrome and Internet Explorer 8.

As you have used position: absolute, I'm not sure how computer margin would affect this layout. Do you mean screen size / browser size - if I view this example in a 1024x768 window, the shape is nearly-off page and I have to scroll, but it is still there. Maybe you could describe the problem in more detail?